# Python app crashed with "PyEval_RestoreThread: the function must be called with the GIL held, but the GIL is released"

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter, crash

I have a Python Program, and because it's too big, here's the link to its source code:
[Link](https://github.com/zcg-coder/pyplussource)

When I run it on Mac, sometimes I get this weird exception:

```
Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: the function must be called with the GIL held, but the GIL is released (the current Python thread state is NULL)
Python runtime state: initialized

Current thread 0x0000000115f8ce00 (most recent call first):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1429 in mainloop
  File ".../PyPlusSource/pyplus.py", line 1435 in <module>
```

So why is this happenning? Please explain in simple words. Thanks for any ideas!

EDIT:
I'm on MacOS 11.2.3 Big Sur [Not beta], with Python 3.9.2 [Not beta again] installed. And this error is hard to reproduce

Comment: Wow, I haven't seen anything like this. I think the error occurs in the python interpreter having problems with the Global Interpreter Lock. What python version are you using? What OS are you running?

Comment: 3.9.2 on MacOS 11.2.3 Big Sur

Comment: You import a module called `pygson`. What's that? I can't find it on PyPi.

Comment: I have done some research, and I found out that it could be caused by lack of memory. Pygson's PyPi name is `Pygments-json` Repo link: https://github.com/orb/pygments-json, by the way

Comment: Open task manager and look at the memory taken up by the process. If it increases a lot, it might be a memory problem.

Comment: Would you mind to share a [mre] for us, that we dont need to guess what you might have done?

Comment: What exactly did you do to get the error? I got it running and haven't encountered any errors

Comment: This problem is hard to reproduce, since you seldom blow up the memory.

Comment: Try hitting `Command+B` or Code->Run sometimes cause the error.

Comment: @AndyZhang it only says *This language is not supported.* for me. What languages does it support?

Comment: You should open a file, using File->Open, Cmd+O, or double click on the treeview. It should at least support Python

Comment: Alright, I reproduced the error, please see this video: https://1drv.ms/v/s!AmSkEnVt2GtHqXaWmxL9hMN4sG_J (onedrive) Download it for better resolution.

Comment: @AndyZhang Try removing all of the unnecessary code line by line until you find which function is causing the bug. You have way too much code to read through. If/When you narrow it down update your question with the function/functions that are causing the issue.

Comment: I tried to remove the excess code, the program works without a problem.

Comment: @AndyZhang Does it mean that your initial problem is solved now? If yes, have you found what was the reason?

Comment: In your video, what exactly did you do before the error occurred? I can only see that in your PyPlus editor, you have clicked the code a couple of times so that mouse pointer moved to another place and a moment later (after having a key pressed? or something else?) the error occurred. Also, I cannot see what part of your code caused the error because in your video, the visible part of pyplus.py are just lines 771-806 but the error is related to line 1452 (non-existent in the current GitHub version), and your original post says it's related to line 1435 (`return` from `comment_lines()`?).

Comment: I pressed command+b

Comment: Okay, this is happening often recently. I figured out that this always happens to me because there's a heavy loop running and I've run out of memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, this should only possibly happen in a code combining Python with components in other languages (typically C; see, e.g., [When the GIL is released?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36949042/when-the-gil-is-released)).

From your description, it's not clear which part of your code causes the error (the original question asked 11 days ago says it's `line 1435`, your video added 6 days ago shows it's `line 1452`, and the PyPlus code at GitHub you refer to was changed 2 days ago and currently only has 1441 lines) and therefore, you'll need to check yourself where exactly in your code the error is produced.

The error further refers to line 1429 in `tkinter/__init__.py` which (as far as I can see in my Python 3.9 version of `tkinter`) is `if string:` in the following function:

```
def _getints(self, string):
    """Internal function."""
    if string:
        return tuple(map(self.tk.getint, self.tk.splitlist(string)))
```

So, it seems that the function is called with undefined variable `string`.

I have got this `PyEval_RestoreThread` error a couple of times with various reasons:

- When a function from a cythonized Python module (`.so` on Mac) calls a function from another module that was imported *only* indirectly. For example, if module `a.py` imports `b.py`, `b.py` imports `c.py`, and a function in `a.py` uses a function from `c.py`. When running from PyCharm or from terminal via `python3 myprogram.py`, there are no errors but as soon as the modules are cythonized, the functions in `a.so` cannot found the functions from `c.so` anymore and I get this error.
- On an uncaught exception in a secondary thread; for example when I haven't checked the type of a variable read from a file and was trying to update a string in my (PySimpleGUI = tkinter-based) GUI with its value that was no string.