# Python Tkinter app using Threading crashes

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading, plotly-dash, chromium-embedded

I've created a tkinter app which shows dash plots as tabs using ttk.Notebbok. The app contains a `new button`, when the it's clicked a dash plot is started in a new `daemon thread` (because I want my Tk app to run) and open the url in tkinter using `cef` in a new tab.

But the problem is, when I click on the new button whilst the previous chart was loading everything crashes. And this is the error log.

```
Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: the function must be called with the GIL held, but the GIL is released (the current Python thread state is NULL)

Python runtime state: initialized

Thread 0x00000518 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\hnagesw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dash\_watch.py", line 36 in watch
  File "C:\Users\hnagesw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1419 in <lambda>
  File "C:\Users\hnagesw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892 in run
  File "C:\Users\hnagesw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\hnagesw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 912 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x000032d0 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\hnagesw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\selectors.py", line 315 in _select
  File "C:\Users\hnagesw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\selectors.py", line 324 in select
  File "C:\Users\hnagesw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\socketserver.py", line 232 in serve_forever
  File "C:\Users\hnagesw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 717 in serve_forever
  File "C:\Users\hnagesw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 961 in inner
  File "C:\Users\hnagesw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 1008 in run_simple
  File "C:\Users\hnagesw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 920 in run
  File "C:\Users\hnagesw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1699 in run_server
  File "C:\Users\hnagesw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 892 in run
  File "C:\Users\hnagesw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 954 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\hnagesw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 912 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0x00000198 (most recent call first):
  File "c:\Throughput-Timing-Tool\UI\browser_screen.py", line 165 in message_loop_work
  File "C:\Users\hnagesw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 814 in callit
  File "C:\Users\hnagesw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\hnagesw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1429 in mainloop
  File "c:\Throughput-Timing-Tool\UI\generate_screen.py", line 229 in generate_screen
  File "c:\Throughput-Timing-Tool\UI\webview.py", line 205 in generate
  File "C:\Users\hnagesw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892 in __call__
  File "C:\Users\hnagesw\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1429 in mainloop
  File "c:\Throughput-Timing-Tool\main_screen.py", line 24 in <module>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python app crashed with "PyEval\_RestoreThread: the function must be called with the GIL held, but the GIL is released"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66795159/python-app-crashed-with-pyeval-restorethread-the-function-must-be-called-with)

Comment: You haven't posted your code but as far as I have learned on here, one shouldn't call tkinter methods from other threads, all of tkinter code has to be contained in one thread, one process, if you want to have threads then a solution is to have the thread, that puts information into queue and to have an `.after` loop that gets from the queue and then updates the according tkinter widgets, but again it would be great to see your code, so please provide a [mre]